# How to plot for repeating values in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to implement an array in R but plotting same y-values for all x values. If value is NA, then it shouldn't be plotted
I tried the following plot which shows the histogram for all 10 values.

```
plot(c(1,2,NA,3,4,5,3,NA,2,4),type='h', ylim=c(0,4))
```

However, for the case below, when I try to control the y-values, the repeated values are not considered in the plot.

```
plot(c(1,2,NA,3,4,5,3,NA,2,4), rep(1,10),type='h', ylim=c(0,4))
```

Is this possible with plot function? Please suggest if the same can be done with an alternative.

Comment: So basically you want to omit NA's from your data and just plot not NA's?

Comment: no, I need a line(of same length) plotted everytime the array has a value. And it will be blank when the value is NA. If you see the first plot, it's the same thing what I need to implement, only requirement is to regulate the y-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look again at the help page of `?plot`.

In your second line you plot the y value `1` at the x values 1 to 5. The plot you get is exactly the plot you asked for, which is not the plot you cared for. In the first plot, your values are interpreted as the y values, not the x values. The x values in the plot are just the indices in the first example.

If you want to get the lines not plotted at the `NA` values, just do:

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,3,4,5,3,NA,2,4)
plot(!is.na(x), type = 'h')
```

Now you plot a `TRUE` (which is a value of 1) whenever there is a value, and `FALSE` (which translates to 0) whenever there is none.

This is the exact same as :

```
xx <- ifelse(is.na(x),0,1)
plot(xx, type = 'h')
```

On a sidenote: Please do not call this a histogram. A histogram represents counts for bins, this doesn't even come close to that.

Comment: thanks, yeah that worked.
And histogram use was just because of 'h' as mentioned in documentation 
["h" for ‘histogram’ like (or ‘high-density’) vertical lines]

Comment: @Aman glad I could help. If this was the answer you needed, you can mark it as the accepted answer using the V symbol on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(!is.na(c(1,2,NA,3,4,5,3,NA,2,4)),type='h', ylim=c(0,4))
```